# XSLT - Converting time to minutes

Tags: xslt

Id like to be able to convert the following XML

```
<itunes:duration>00:09:54</itunes:duration>
```

To a total of minutes, I currently just output the complete value but I would like to just display: 0hr 9min 54sec

Or possibly round up to the nearest minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an XPath 2.0 supporting processor, there are built in functions you can use. [Here's a list](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp), scroll down to the date/time functions.

You probably want something like: minutes-from-time(time)

Watch out for namespace prefixes etc. A prefix isn't required for the functions if your processor dows support XPath 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to round up you can substring minutes and seconds, and if seconds > 30 -> minutes += 1